# Join two tables including connecting the columns first on both table and then comparing both the table

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I have 2 data sets  in the same excel file but in two sheets, let's say the sheets are:

```
Order ID        Product ID      Qty
CA-2014-100006  TEC-PH-10002075 3
CA-2014-100090  FUR-TA-10003715 3
CA-2014-100090  OFF-BI-10001597 6
CA-2014-100293  OFF-PA-10000176 6
CA-2014-100328  OFF-BI-10000343 1
CA-2014-100363  OFF-FA-10000611 2
CA-2014-100363  OFF-PA-10004733 3
CA-2014-100391  OFF-PA-10001471 2
CA-2014-100678  FUR-CH-10002602 3
```

And the 2nd is:

```
Order ID        Product ID      Qty
CA-2014-100090  FUR-TA-10003715 3
CA-2014-100090  OFF-BI-10001597 6
CA-2014-100293  OFF-PA-10000176 6
CA-2014-100328  OFF-BI-10000343 1
CA-2014-100363  OFF-FA-10000611 2
CA-2014-100363  OFF-PA-10004733 3
CA-2014-100391  OFF-PA-10001471 2
CA-2014-100678  FUR-CH-10002602 3
CA-2014-100678  OFF-AR-10001868 2
CA-2014-100678  TEC-AC-10000474 3
```

How can I identify `(orderid + product id)` combination present in table 1 but missing in table 2 and vice versa?

first, I concatenated the first two columns in table 1 and then in table 2, then I wanted to compare both the tables with the new concatenated column where I failed. I don't know how to put the output from SQL in a new table.

Trying to do this in a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Having these sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE orders1 (
  order_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  product_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  qty INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id, product_id)
);

CREATE TABLE orders2 (
  order_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  product_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  qty INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (order_id, product_id)
);


INSERT INTO orders1 (order_id, product_id, qty)
VALUES
  ('CA-2014-100006', 'TEC-PH-10002075', 3),
  ('CA-2014-100090', 'FUR-TA-10003715', 3),
  ('CA-2014-100090', 'OFF-BI-10001597', 6),
  ('CA-2014-100293', 'OFF-PA-10000176', 6),
  ('CA-2014-100328', 'OFF-BI-10000343', 1),
  ('CA-2014-100363', 'OFF-FA-10000611', 2),
  ('CA-2014-100363', 'OFF-PA-10004733', 3),
  ('CA-2014-100391', 'OFF-PA-10001471', 2),
  ('CA-2014-100678', 'FUR-CH-10002602', 3);

INSERT INTO orders2 (order_id, product_id, qty)
VALUES
  ('CA-2014-100090', 'FUR-TA-10003715', 3),
  ('CA-2014-100090', 'OFF-BI-10001597', 6),
  ('CA-2014-100 293', 'OFF-PA-10000176', 6),
  ('CA-2014-100328', 'OFF-BI-10000343', 1),
  ('CA-2014-100363', 'OFF-FA-10000611', 2),
  ('CA-2014-100363', 'OFF-PA-10004733', 3),
  ('CA-2014-100391', 'OFF-PA-10001471', 2),
  ('CA-2014-100678', 'FUR-CH-10002602', 3),
  ('CA-2014-100678', 'OFF-AR-10001868', 2),
  ('CA-2014-100678', 'TEC-AC-10000474', 3);
```

You can use the following statements:

```
-- records not found in table orders1
SELECT A.*
FROM orders1 A
LEFT JOIN orders2 B
    ON A.order_id = B.order_id
    AND A.product_id = B.product_id
WHERE B.order_id IS NULL;

-- records not found in table orders2
SELECT A.*
FROM orders2 A
LEFT JOIN orders1 B
    ON A.order_id = B.order_id
    AND A.product_id = B.product_id
WHERE B.order_id IS NULL;

-- records found in both tables
SELECT A.*
FROM orders1 A
INNER JOIN orders2 B
    ON A.order_id = B.order_id
    AND A.product_id = B.product_id;
```

You can combine them in one statement using [UNION ALL](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/union_all.php) and insert it in a new table.

Comment: The thing is i have already an excel file  and in result i want to join  order_id+product_id  and then compare both tables